# Cassandra query collection while specifying a partition key

Tags: cassandra

I've been reading about indexes in Cassandra but I'm a little confused when it comes to creating an index on a collection like a set, list or map.

Let's say I have the following table and index on users like the following

```
CREATE TABLE chatter.channels (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    users set<text>
); 

CREATE INDEX channels_users_idx ON chatter.channels (values(users));

INSERT INTO chatter.channels (id, users) VALUE ('ch1', {'jeff', 'jenny'});
```

In the docs, at least what I've found so far, says that this can have a huge performance hit because the indexes are created local on the nodes. And all the examples that are given query the tables like below

```
SELECT * FROM chatter.channels WHERE users CONTAINS 'jeff';
```

From my understanding this would have the performance hit because the partition key is not specified and all nodes must be queried. However, if I was to issue a query like below

```
SELECT * FROM chatter.channels WHERE id = 'ch1' AND users CONTAINS 'jeff';
```

(giving the partition key) then would I still have the performance hit?

How would I be able to check this for myself? In SQL I can run EXPLAIN and get some useful information.  Is there something similar in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra provides tracing capability , this helps to trace the progression of reads and writes of queries in Cassandra.

To view traces, open -> cqlsh on one of your Cassandra nodes and run the following command:

```
cqlsh> tracing on;
Now tracing requests.
cqlsh> use [KEYSPACE];
```

I hope this helps in checking the performance of query.